# MySQL stuck in EXPLAIN statement

Tags: mysql, explain

I am trying to debug the following query.

```
# Projects with at least 50 members with at least 240 yearly commits each
select project_id, count(*) as active_members from
(
        select project_members.repo_id as project_id, project_members.user_id, count(*)
        from project_members
        inner join yearly_project_commits on project_members.user_id = yearly_project_commits.committer_id and project_members.repo_id = yearly_project_commits.project_id
        group by project_members.repo_id, project_members.user_id
        having count(*) > 240
) as active_member_projects
group by project_id
having count(*) > 50;
```

Originally, it run for days without producing any result. At the point where I interrupted the query's execution, MySQL was not consuming any significant CPU time and not issuing any system calls (shown by running *strace* on the *mysqld* process).  At that point the output of `show processlist` gave the following result.

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User      | Host      | db        | Command | Time   | State        | Info                                                                                                 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 55 | ghtorrent | localhost | ghtorrent | Query   | 217907 | Sending data | select project_id, count(*) as active_members from
(
        select project_members.repo_id as project_id,  |
| 69 | ghtorrent | localhost | ghtorrent | Query   |      0 | NULL         | show processlist                                                                                     |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I also tried running `EXPLAIN` on the query, but this also gets stuck, with `show processlist` showing the following.

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User      | Host      | db        | Command | Time | State                        | Info                                                                                                 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10 | ghtorrent | localhost | ghtorrent | Query   |  564 | Copying to tmp table on disk | explain select populous_projects.name, members, count(populous_projects.project_id) as yearly_projec |
| 40 | ghtorrent | localhost | ghtorrent | Query   |    1 | NULL                         | show processlist                                                                                     |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Running EXPLAIN on the inner query gives me

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type  | possible_keys           | key        | key_len | ref                               | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | project_members        | index | PRIMARY,user_id         | PRIMARY    | 8       | NULL                              | 53530 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | yearly_project_commits | ref   | committer_id,project_id | project_id | 4       | ghtorrent.project_members.repo_id |   113 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

and I see that indices are defined for the fields used.

```
mysql> show indexes from yearly_project_commits;
+------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                  | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| yearly_project_commits |          1 | committer_id |            1 | committer_id | A         |     2535097 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| yearly_project_commits |          1 | project_id   |            1 | project_id   | A         |     7134168 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

mysql> show indexes from project_members;
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| project_members |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | repo_id     | A         |     5559879 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| project_members |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | user_id     | A         |     5559879 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| project_members |          1 | user_id  |            1 | user_id     | A         |     5559879 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The corresponding `create table` commands are as follows.

```
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table           | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| project_members | CREATE TABLE `project_members` (
  `repo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ext_ref_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`repo_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `project_members_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`repo_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `project_members_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
| yearly_project_commits | CREATE TABLE `yearly_project_commits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `author_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `committer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  KEY `committer_id` (`committer_id`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The output of `show full processlist` at the time `EXPLAIN` is running is the following.

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User      | Host      | db        | Command | Time  | State        | Info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 43 | ghtorrent | localhost | ghtorrent | Query   | 53434 | Sending data | explain
    select project_id, count(*) as active_members from
    (
            select project_members.repo_id as project_id, project_members.user_id, count(*)
            from project_members
            inner join yearly_project_commits on project_members.user_id = yearly_project_commits.committer_id and project_members.repo_id = yearly_project_commits.project_id
            group by project_members.repo_id, project_members.user_id
            having count(*) > 240
    ) as active_member_projects
    group by project_id
    having count(*) > 50 |
| 47 | ghtorrent | localhost | ghtorrent | Query   |     0 | NULL         | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

These things happen on an otherwise idle machine running MySQL Server version 5.5.43-0+deb8u1 (Debian) under Debian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie).  The machine has 24GB of RAM and configured with `innodb_buffer_pool_size=1GB`.

All tables apart from `yearly_project_commits`, which uses MyISAM (it is a read-only table created to simplify a more complex query) use InnoDB.

Comment: Have you checked SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST for locks on the tables active_member_projects and project_members?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I added the details you both proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some queries EXPLAIN tries to run some subqueries to get the stats - it is [a known bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44802) which is fixed in 5.6 and in MariaDB (10 at least, not sure about 5.5).

Your indexes are not good enough - you have two single-column indexes on `yearly_project_commits` - but the query can use only one at a time.

You should create one multicolumn index with both the columns `(project_id, committer_id)` - that should turn the subquery into index-only scan with direct access in join and make it substantially faster.

Comment: Thank you!  I am adding the index you suggest, and will report back.  Why can't the query use both indices?  This would make the query a 2 * O(log N) operation instead of O(N log N) if it is using only one index.

Comment: That is MySQL limitation (but afaik other database systems have it quite similar) - one index per joined table. There are possible exceptions with "index merge" but their usability is quite limited (it means scanning two indexes and mergign the results - instead one ref access you have two full index scans - that will help only in some specific cases).

Comment: After creating the multicolumn index the queries I was running finished in a couple of hours. Thank you!